# send html email using html form and php?

Tags: php, html, email

Hi im trying to create my own simple mailing list so i can send html email to multiple email  addressses by typing the email in the form and hitting send.

i just want to send an email i dont want to store the information in a database but i cant get it to work. please cans someone show me where im going wrong.

so here's my form:

```
Send Email:
<form class="" method="post" action="SEND_EMAIL.php">


                <div class="row email">
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"  />
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Next >"  />

            </form>
```

then heres my send email code, but am i right in thinnking that a html form can action to send_email.php and send an email?

```
<p>Email Was Sent Mark!</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<?php

/**
 * ShuttleCMS - A basic CMS coded in PHP.

 * 
 * @author Dan <dan@danbriant.com>
 * @version 0.0.1
 * @package ShuttleCMS
 */
define('IN_SCRIPT', true);
// Start a session
session_start();


//Generate a RANDOM MD5 Hash for a password
$random_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

/
<?php

 $subjectconfirm = "email.com - Registration";
 $headersconfirm = "To: $email\r\n"; 
 $headersconfirm .= "From: email.com <registrations@email.com>\r\n";                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 $headersconfirm .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

  $sep = sha1(date('r', time()));
 $bodyconfirm =<<<EOF

BLAH BLAH BLHA
EOF;


 // Finally, send the email
 mail('registrations@email.com', $subjectconfirm, $bodyconfirm, $headersconfirm);

?>
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: You specified the recipient address both in `$headersconfirm` and in the first parameter, and they differ.

Comment: Why do you even need session, if all you want is to type in mail and send password

Comment: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/31/9118831/html/send/send_email.php:4) in /home/content/31/9118831/html/send/send_email.php on line 16

i get these two errors: Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/31/9118831/html/send/send_email.php:4) in /home/content/31/9118831/html/send/send_email.php on line 16

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the mail - just move the `session_start()` command to the to of the page.

Comment: ive removed the session as i dont need this, and now i dont get any errors but the emails are still not being sent

Comment: right before `$subjectconfirm = "email.com - Registration";` you have another error. You already have opened a php segment and you try to start another one. `/
<?php`

Comment: Are you able to write a simple php script that sends an email? No forms, no variables... This would confirm that your basic setup is such that you can send emails (say, to yourself). Then add variables, then a call from the other page...

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your system or php for email sending?

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer. To make this an answer, you would explain what steps to take to configure a typical system. Hard to do without knowing more about the environment...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code you have unnecessary stuff in your email form. For example, you do not need `md5` for an email form because you do not have a password that you need to encrypt and `session_start` is also unnecessary because it does not need to be remembered so no storage for SQL.

```
<p>Email Was Sent Mark!</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<?php

define('IN_SCRIPT', true);

<?php

 $subjectconfirm = "email.com - Registration";
 $to = "To: $email\r\n"; 
 $h .= "From: email.com <registrations@email.com>\r\n";                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 $headersconfirm .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

  $sep = sha1(date('r', time()));
 $bodyconfirm =<<<EOF

BLAH BLAH BLHA
EOF;


 // Finally, send the email
 mail('registrations@email.com', $to, $subjectconfirm, $bodyconfirm, $h, $headersconfirm);

?>
```